# Impossible to mount an Nginx container with custom config

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to mount an Nginx container through a `docker-compose.yml` with configuration files shared with volumes.

Here are the `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: lamp

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      # - ./log:/var/log/nginx
      # - ./code:/usr/share/nginx/html

  php:
    image: phpdockerio/php73-fpm
    depends_on:
      - db
```

The `nginx.conf`

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And the `default.conf`

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

The issue is, when I run `docker-compose up`, I get those errors

```
ERROR: for lamp-compose_nginx_1  Cannot start service nginx: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/host_mnt/e/Projects/lamp-compose/docker/nginx/default.conf\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/15cb114888ab7570fd7da633798ef7f094049965e83d4f4ca5500f7d4a833706/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/15cb114888ab7570fd7da633798ef7f09Creating lamp-compose_php_1        ... done
ied host path exists and is the expected type

ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/host_mnt/e/Projects/lamp-compose/docker/nginx/default.conf\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/15cb114888ab7570fd7da633798ef7f094049965e83d4f4ca5500f7d4a833706/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/15cb114888ab7570fd7da633798ef7f094049965e83d4f4ca5500f7d4a833706/merged/etc/nginx/conf.d\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I already saw some answers to similar issue saying I should change `- ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to `- ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/` which makes no sense to me (and also is not working).

Would anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Can you remove the link, and copy the actual Nginx configuration and any other details necessary to reproduce the issue into the question itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the linked error, it seems that one of the paths `./docker/nginx/nginx.conf, ./docker/nginx/default.conf` is a directory and not a file.

Instead of adding the configuration files as volumes, I recommend that you. use a custom docker image for Nginx with your configurations in it. You need to change the docker-compose file and provide a docker file for Nginx as shown below

Dockerfile

```
From nginx:latest

COPY ./docker/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

compose

```
  nginx:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8000:80
```